# Converting column arrays to alternating rows

Tags: r, matlab, matrix, coordinates, reshape

From the following format ... (`x1-x27`, `y1-y27` being numeric `x,y` coordinates which need to be moved to a single row, for each subj.)

```
Subj    X   Y
1   x1  y1
1   x2  y2
1   x3  y3
1   x4  y4
1   x5  y5
1   x6  y6
1   x7  y7
1   x8  y8
1   x9  y9
2   x10 y10
2   x11 y11
2   x12 y12
2   x13 y13
2   x14 y14
2   x15 y15
2   x16 y16
2   x17 y17
2   x18 y18
3   x19 y19
3   x20 y20
3   x21 y21
3   x22 y22
3   x23 y23
3   x24 y24
3   x25 y25
3   x26 y26
3   x27 y27
```

to the format as shown below:

```
Subj    X   Y                                                               
1   x1  y1  x2  y2  x3  y3  x4  y4  x5  y5  x6  y6  x7  y7  x8  y8  x9  y9
2   x10 y10 x11 y11 x12 y12 x13 y13 x14 y14 x15 y15 x16 y16 x17 y17 x18 y18
3   x19 y19 x20 y20 x21 y21 x22 y22 x23 y23 x24 y24 x25 y25 x26 y26 x27 y27
```

I want to do this either using R or MATLAB R2016a.

Comment: In MATLAB: [transpose](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/transpose.html) then [reshape](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) then transpose again.

Comment: Your question is still open, i.e, you haven't accepted one of the answers. Does this mean that none of the answers solved your problem?

Comment: If one/some of the answers helped you, please accept\upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it in MATLAB R2016b:

```matlab
in = [repelem(1:3,9).' ...
      strcat(string('x'), string((1:27).')) ...
      strcat(string('y'), string((1:27).'))];

u = unique(in(:,1)); 
out = [u reshape(in(:,2:3).', [], numel(u)).'];
```

In older versions you'd probably be working with a cell array instead of `string` variables (unless `x1...y27` are actually numbers, in which case a regular array would do).

Comment: Yes... x1 - x27, y1-y27 are actual X, Y co-ordinates, which I need to move in a single row depending on the first column.

Comment: @Roopali This is the kind of information that should appear in the **question itself**. You should also mention which version of MATLAB you have at your disposal. You always have the same amount of points belonging to `1` as you have to `2` and `3`, right? Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42466022/edit) the question and include it.

Comment: @Roopali There's still some information missing. Regardless - does this code not solve your problem? (Ignore the `in = ...`, I only used it to generate the input.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way on Matlab, using linear indexing (assuming that the subject numbers are positive integers):

```matlab
data = [repelem([1 2 4],4).' randi(50,12,2)]; % some data...
%% code start here: %%
unsubj = unique(data(:,1)); % get unique subjucts numbers
coordsN = numel(data(:,2:end))/numel(unsubj); % no. data values per subject
% linear indices for the data
coord_ind = bsxfun(@plus,unsubj,0:max(unsubj):coordsN*max(unsubj)-1).';
output = zeros(max(unsubj),coordsN); % initialize the output
output(coord_ind(:)) = data(:,2:3).'; % fill the output matrix
subjT(unsubj) = unsubj; % make the first column
output = [subjT.' output]; % add the subect column
```

The advantage with this solution is that it can take also non-continuous row numbers as input for the subject (as in the example in the code above).

Answer (score 0):

In `R`, you may use `data.table` to reshape. This is the most flexible approach as neither the number of different `Subj` is restricted, nor the number of coordinates for each `Subj`.

```
library(data.table)
DTM <- melt(DT, id.var = "Subj")
dcast(DTM, Subj ~ rowid(Subj, variable) + variable, value.var = "value")
#   Subj 1_X 1_Y 2_X 2_Y 3_X 3_Y 4_X 4_Y 5_X 5_Y 6_X 6_Y 7_X 7_Y 8_X 8_Y 9_X 9_Y
#1:    1  x1  y1  x2  y2  x3  y3  x4  y4  x5  y5  x6  y6  x7  y7  x8  y8  x9  y9
#2:    2 x10 y10 x11 y11 x12 y12 x13 y13 x14 y14 x15 y15 x16 y16 x17 y17 x18 y18
#3:    3 x19 y19 x20 y20 x21 y21 x22 y22 x23 y23 x24 y24 x25 y25 x26 y26 x27 y27
```

First, `DT` is reshaped from wide to long format, so that all coordinates are 
in a `value` column. The `variable` column contains "X" and "Y" to indicate the original column names the values are taken from.

Then, the molten data `DTM` are reshaped from long to wide. Thereby, a row index is created on the fly which corresponds to the row numbers for each `Subj` in the original `DT`. Columns are ordered by this row index first, then by variable name to ensure that the `X` and `Y` values appear in alternating order.

In case, the number of coordinates are different for each group the missing column values would be filled up with NA.

This could be combined in one line of code:

```
dcast(melt(DT, id.var = "Subj"), Subj ~ rowid(Subj, variable) + variable, value.var = "value")
```

Note that there is another approach using `matrix` but this requires more lines of code and is less flexible as the number of coordinate pairs has to be the same for all `Subj`.

---

#### Data

```
DT <- structure(list(Subj = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L), X = c("x1", "x2", "x3", "x4", "x5", "x6", "x7", "x8", "x9", 
"x10", "x11", "x12", "x13", "x14", "x15", "x16", "x17", "x18", 
"x19", "x20", "x21", "x22", "x23", "x24", "x25", "x26", "x27"
), Y = c("y1", "y2", "y3", "y4", "y5", "y6", "y7", "y8", "y9", 
"y10", "y11", "y12", "y13", "y14", "y15", "y16", "y17", "y18", 
"y19", "y20", "y21", "y22", "y23", "y24", "y25", "y26", "y27"
)), .Names = c("Subj", "X", "Y"), row.names = c(NA, -27L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))
```

Answer (score -1):

Use concatenation and find(), it is very simple. Here is a sample code :

```
clc;clear;close;

SubjectMatrix=[
1  ,11  ,21;
1  ,12  ,22;
1  ,13  ,23;
1  ,14  ,24;
1  ,15  ,25;
1  ,16  ,26;
1  ,17  ,27;
1  ,18  ,28;
1  ,19  ,29;
2  ,110 ,210;
2  ,111 ,211;
2  ,112 ,212;
2  ,113 ,213;
2  ,114 ,214;
2  ,115 ,215;
2  ,116 ,216;
2  ,117 ,217;
2  ,118 ,218;
3  ,119 ,219;
3  ,120 ,220;
3  ,121 ,221;
3  ,122 ,222;
3  ,123 ,223;
3  ,124 ,224;
3  ,125 ,225;
3  ,126 ,226;
3  ,127 ,227; ];

Subject1=[];
Subject2=[];
Subject3=[];

Matcoor=find(SubjectMatrix(:,1)==1);
for i=1:length(Matcoor)
    Subject1=[Subject1 SubjectMatrix(Matcoor(i),2:3)];%concatenation
end

Matcoor=find(SubjectMatrix(:,1)==2);
for i=1:length(Matcoor)
    Subject2=[Subject2 SubjectMatrix(Matcoor(i),2:3)];%concatenation
end

Matcoor=find(SubjectMatrix(:,1)==3);
for i=1:length(Matcoor)
    Subject3=[Subject3 SubjectMatrix(Matcoor(i),2:3)];%concatenation
end
```

Comment: And what happens when there are 20 groups and not just 3...? Copy-pasting code is indication of bad design.

Comment: Use a for loop, simple as that

Comment: Well, if you're suggesting a nested `for` loop, why beat around the bush? Just put it in your answer and be done with it :)

Comment: Dynamically growing arrays in loops is a time disaster. Each time you update your array it writes it to a copy, appends the new value(s), and deletes the original. This can easily slow down your code by a factor 100 or more, especially for large arrays. Please don't do that, just initialise your arrays to the final size first.